# get next link outside current html nest

Tags: jquery, html, frontend

I have a form when an action is performed on the form I am trying to get the link `'/form/foo'` after the form.

I am running jQuery that executes when enter is pressed within the text area, what I am trying to retrieve is the link at the bottom with href `/form/foo`. The `jQuery` is below

I am trying to traverse back to the parent wrapper then find the a.form link is this subset, but I always get undefined returned.

Thanks for any help.

```js
$('.form-wrapper textarea').on('keypress', function(e) {
  if (e.which == 13) {
    alert($(this).closest('.wrapper').find('a.form-link').attr('href'));
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper wrapper-id-x">
  <div class="example-content">...</div>
  <form>
    <div class="form-wrapper">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
          ...
        </div>
        <div class="col">
          <label>Form </label>
          <div class="form-text-wrapper">
            <textarea></textarea>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="author">
      <span class="username">author</span>
    </div>
    <input>
    <input>
    <input>
    <div class="action"><button>Save</button>
    </div>
  </form>
  <a href="/form/foo" class="form-link loaded"></a>
</div>
```

Comment: Your code works fine as a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9fh6u4wt/).

Comment: I edited your code in to an executable snippet where it works fine. Check that you've included jQuery.js in the page correctly and are running your code when the DOM has loaded. Also check in dev tools to see if there's any errors in the console